# After database update coroutine is completed, set boolean flag

Tags: android, asynchronous, kotlin, coroutine

I want to set a livedata boolean flag to true once the coroutine for saving data into the database is completed. My current code is as follows:

In ViewModel:

```
    private suspend fun updatePlace(eventId: Long, placeName: String, placeAddress: String) {
        withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            repository.updatePlace(placeName, placeAddress)
        }
    }

    fun savePlace(placeName: String, placeAddress: String) {
        val eventId = event.value!!.eId

        uiScope.launch {
            updatePlace(eventId, placeName, placeAddress)
        }
        //flag is currently set regardless of if the updatePlace function is completed
        _currentPlaceUpdated.value = true

    }
```

I've been reading about async and await for coroutine but haven't figured out how to set the value of _currentPlaceUpdated after the updatePlace() function is completed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put the completion task after the `updatePlace` call.

```kotlin
uiScope.launch {
    updatePlace(eventId, placeName, placeAddress)
    _currentPlaceUpdated.value = true
}
```

`withContext` is similar to `scope.async(Dispatchers.IO) { /* Code */ }.await()` with some optimization over delivery of return value.

`withContext` suspends the current calling coroutine till the inside of it (block of code) completes. What `launch` does is launch the coroutine and let the next code execute that's why it is being called immediately.

Comment: Thanks! I tried to add it inside "withContext(Dispatchers.IO)" instead of "uiScope.launch", and that's why it didn't work earlier.